# API Design: For servers with multiple functions

Tags: api, api-design

Suppose I have a server with the following two jobs:

1. Handle a payment using Stripe
2. Connect to a DB with a list of posts/products/items

What would be the best approach: 
Have all the calls go to /api/
eg. /api/payment and /api/posts

Or since the payment is not as extensive and is a smaller function have it separate: 
/payment
and the posts goes to /api/posts and you can GET, POST on that

Just trying to understand the best practices, please let me know if I'm way off base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could prefix everything with some prefix, such as /api

This makes sense for example when there are different kinds of APIs.
if this is not intended, why should you choose such an approach?

We are in a similar discussion, we go for:

- /portal
- /mobile
- /...

as acces paths for different accesses and devices. Then, under this, we have the resources used by the access paths.

As your request is not very detailed, I would rather go for

- /posts
- /payments

Keep in mind, a stateless design is very helpful.